# Как в Xcode создать реализацию проекта и поместить в Launchpad?

Tags: xcode, macos, objective-c

Я закончил свой проект для Mac OS в Xcode, как мне теперь пользоваться им без Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте выбрать в левой боковой вкладке цель проекта (target) и нажать показать в файндере, по идее оно перекинет туда где валяется откомпилированный бандл с программой (если вы ее конечно собирали на этом компе). Скопируйте этот бандл в папку Программы (Applications)